# Is there a possibility to edit your own answers some time later, without the question being pushed somewhere to the top of the "Active Questions"?

Tags: discussion, editing, best-practice

Is there a possibility to edit your own answers some time later, without the question being pushed somewhere to the top of the "Active Questions" and without the question attracting attention and thus distracting from more current problems?

I ask this because I tend to tinker for rather aesthetic or "didactic" reasons with older answers written by me.
For example, English is not my native language and sometimes it takes me a while to figure out how to more eloquently phrase things in English language.
Sometimes I realize later that I assumed knowledge of matters that should be explained.
Sometimes inaccuracies/flaws in my text need rectification.

Often I don't introduce fundamentally new aspects or changes to code examples, but I go more into reference to basic concepts —which the advanced questioner may not need, but which could be useful to the novice looking for answers with the search function—, or I rephrase text passages so that my explanations become more understandable and/or more precise, or at least seem more understandable and/or more precise to me.

Often it's about answers to questions that aren't pressing anyone at the moment, so it is not useful to push them up in the Active Questions, but despite this I'd like the text to look good for those people who are looking for answers with the search function.
Besides, in such cases my editing could be interpreted as hustling for attention and upvotes, and I would like to avoid this impression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, by design all<sup>*</sup> edits move material to the top of the active page. This is to avoid e.g. self-destruction of posts, 'minor' edits which make significant changes, etc.

<sub><sup>*</sup> The Powers can of course make edits where this is not the case.</sub>

Comment: As a follow-up, I would say it's not a problem to bump a question or two to the Active Questions page (even Community does this on occasion).  The problem is when you edit many questions in a short period of time, and flood the Active Questions page.  (This often happens when someone is changing a particular tag.)

Comment: +1 Maybe a language barrier, but what do you mean by "self-destruction of posts"?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It's quite frequent in other StackExchange sites: users that vandalize their own post for various reasons.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the reply. I am apparently naive and did not know about that :)